# CefSharp webview is closed when return key is press

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have this frame:

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"></Frame>
```

When I load a PAGE in this frame like this

```
MainFrame.Navigate(testWebView = new TestWebView(e.Url));
if (MainFrame.CanGoBack)
{
    MainFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

in the testview class I have a cefsharp webview

```
<Grid Name="CefSharpContainer">
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Name="webview" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

the constructor of the webview is:

```
public TestWebView(string url)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = ViewModelTestBase.Instance;

    webview.FrameLoadEnd += CefSharp1_FrameLoadEnd;
    webview.Address = url;
}
```

When I press return key, webview is closed and return to back Page.
I have tried to get return key event but nothing happen.
Any solution?

Comment: What have you tried exactly?

Comment: Are you sure it's enter and not backspace? I expect backspace to navigate back

Comment: I tried this:  private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... Test for F5 key.
            if (e.Key == Key.Back)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Key);
                return;
            }
        }

Comment: Please don't post code as comments, attempting to handle a key press at the window level is unlikely to work, also add some debugging to work out what key press actually takes place, you said enter yet you are checking for back